# getTop method return wrong result

Tags: java, android

I have a problem while getting the "top" value of a view.
When I use "post" method:

```
chart.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        chart.getTop()// return 382 (wrong)
    }
});
```

But when I use "setOnClickListener" to set an event handler and watch the result at run time, it give a different value

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(AnNhau.this,chart.getTop() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //return 298 (right)
    }
});
```

The problem here is I want to re-position the "**chart**" view right before user can see it.

Comment: That `Toast` should be throwing a `Resources$NotFoundException`. Anyway, when and where are you posting that `Runnable`? Is it before you reposition the chart?

Comment: Hi Mike.M, i post that **Runable** in **OnCreate** event. I use it to get the current **Top** of the chart first. Base on that i will re-position later.